# Dojox Calendar ColumnView week view defaulted to 8AM

Tags: dojo

I need to load a dojo calendar's week view defaulted to 8 AM. The time should start from 12 AM. But when we open calendar it should have scrolled to 8AM. (using startTimeOFDay or scrollToPosition). I use ColumnView. the calendar is inside a portlet.

```
calendar = new DayCalendar({

                startTimeAttr: "begin",
                endTimeAttr: "end",

                cssClassFunc: function(item){
                return item.calendar;
                },
                   store: new Observable(new Memory({data: daatArray})),
                   dateInterval: "day",
                   style: "border:1px solid grey;position:relative;width:88%;height:88%",
                   columnViewProps:{minHours:0,maxHours:24}

            }, "day1");
calendar.columnView.set("startTimeOfDay", {hours:9, duration:1000});
```

Tried the above, but when i open calendar it shows 12 AM only. Please help.

I have the code in JSFiddle- jsfiddle.net/libinjose/N4YCw/5. I have edited CalendarBase.js,PortletDialogSettings.js- jsfiddle.net/libinjose/VkQUH. Added new DayCalendar.js which uses DayCalendar.html. Similarly for week and month view. These can be found in the second JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following in latest chrome and firefox browser. The view is defaulted to the required 8 AM. Hope it offers you some clue to your problem.

```
<body class="claro">

    <div id="someId" > </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        require(["dojo/parser", "dojo/ready", "dojox/calendar/Calendar"],
                function(parser, ready, Calendar){
                    ready(function(){
                                calendar = new Calendar({
                                    date: new Date(2012, 0, 1),
                                    dateInterval: "day",
                                    columnViewProps:{minHours:0,maxHours:24},
                                    style: "position:relative;width:600px;height:600px"
                                }, "someId");

                                calendar.columnView.set("startTimeOfDay", {hours:8, duration:1000});
                            }
                    )}
        );
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: I am using IE 8. Is it the reason , mine doesnt get set to 8AM

Comment: I have the code in JSFiddle-jsfiddle.net/libinjose/N4YCw/5. I have edited CalendarBase.js,PortletDialogSettings.js-jsfiddle.net/libinjose/VkQUH. Added new DayCalendar.js which uses DayCalendar.html. Similarly for week and month view. These can be found in the second JSFiddle.